# Convert/Map one Jackson POJO to Different Jackson POJO

Tags: java, jackson

I have an input that is a Jackson PoJo and I need to convert it to a different Jackson Pojo. All examples I am finding are from Json -> Pojo and Pojo -> Json. Is creating a custom serializer the way to convert from one Pojo to another?

Answer (score 1):

If the field names match, or have aliases defined, you could simply serialize one object and deserialize into the other; e.g.

```
objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(object1), Object2.class)
```

If the fields don't align one-to-one, there isn't a direct way

Therefore, you have some other options

- Copy constructor / Factory method : `new Object2(object1)` or `Object2.from(object1)`
- Builder / setter : `object2.setX(object1.getX()); // repeat for all fields`
- Use a library like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) (effectively the same as options above)
- Use reflection (very brittle and only to be used if you don't have access to modify either class)

Answer (score 1):

ModelMapper, like OneCricketeer said, or [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) can do the job of mapping one POJO to another POJO.

Comment: nah, Jackson objectmapper already has a convert method on it

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***MapStruct*** like below:

1. Add `MapStruct` dependency:

   ```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
       <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.2.Final</version>  
     </dependency>
   ```

Example-

Car.java

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private int seatCount;
    private CarType type;
    //constructor, getters, setters etc.
}
```

CarDto.java

```
public class CarDto {
    private String make;
    private int seatCount;
    private String type;
    //constructor, getters, setters etc.
}
```

CarMapper.java

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
 
    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class );
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
    Car carDtoToCar(CarDto carDto);
}
```

Use:

```
public void shouldMapCarToDto() {

    Car car = new Car( "Morris", 5, CarType.SEDAN );
    // mapping Car to carDto
    CarDto carDto = CarMapper.INSTANCE.carToCarDto(car);
}
```

**For more details-> [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/#get-started)**